# how can I center the title in a progressDialog android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to center the title in a progressDialog, I am trying to do it using styles

```
  <style name="progressDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/popup_main_title</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/popup_main_title</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/popup_main_title</item>
</style>


 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.progressDialogTheme);
        progressDialog.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.firmware_downloading_firmware_title));
        progressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.firmware_downloading_firmware_message));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a custom title:

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.progressDialogTheme);
    TextView tvTitle = new TextView(context);
    tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvTitle.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.firmware_downloading_firmware_title));
    progressDialog.setCustomTitle(tvTitle);
    progressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.firmware_downloading_firmware_message));
```

Of course you can change other attributes of the title TextView, like text color and background color.

Comment: Easiest solution around..!

Comment: I believe so___

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="progressDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/popup_main_title</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/popup_main_title</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/popup_main_title</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressDialog` is deprecated so you can use `AlertDialog` as `ProgressDialog` refer below code for the `ProgressDialog`. This function you need to call whenever you show a progress dialog.

**Code:**

```
    public void setProgressDialog() {

    int llPadding = 30;
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    ll.setPadding(llPadding, llPadding, llPadding, llPadding);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    ll.setLayoutParams(llParam);

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setPadding(0, 0, llPadding, 0);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(llParam);

    llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    TextView tvText = new TextView(this);
    tvText.setText("Loading ...");
    tvText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    tvText.setTextSize(20);
    tvText.setLayoutParams(llParam);

    ll.addView(progressBar);
    ll.addView(tvText);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setView(ll);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]